# jQuery: how do I check if an element is the last sibling?

Tags: jquery

How do I check if an element is the last sibling?

For the last cell in a row I want to perform a different action.

This doesn't work:

```
$('td').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this === $this.parent().last('td') )
        {
            alert('123');
        }
})
```

And neither does it if I remove `.parent()`.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because you're comparing two jQuery objects with each other. Objects are only ever equal if they are exactly the same object. `$(this) == $(this)` is false.. Crazy stuff. You example would work if you did `if ( $this.get(0) === $this.parent().last('td').get(0) )`, as it compares the actual DOM elements. (http://api.jquery.com/get)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$('tr td:last-child').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('123');
});
```

Answer (score 325):

This is more elegant and worked for me:

```
if($(this).is(':last-child'))
{
    alert('123');
}
```

Comment: this is way better than selecting the object directly by css. you can use this on variables too.

Comment: I want to know why not `$(this).is(':last')` work like above one.

Comment: @SkuraZZ There is a subtle difference betweem the selectors; :last-child selects all elements that are the last child of their parent, :last selects the last matched element (see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 8):

Here you go, but that only make sense if you want to do something to the other tds as well other wise use the **last-child** method described in one of the other answers.

```
$('td').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.index() == $this.siblings().length-1)
        {
            alert('123');
        }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

you can code this way.

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.index()==$this.siblings().size()-1)
{
   alert("It's the last.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select multiple elements which are different tags with a common point, (for ex: all *data-foo* attribute defined tags like divs, inputs, text areas, etc.) you can follow this code:

```
var elements = $("*[data-foo]");

elements.each(function (){
    ..
    ..your code
    ..

    if (elements.index(this) == elements.length - 1) {
            ..you are at the end, do something else
    }
})
```