# Determining if the element is the last child of its parent

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, is there a quick way of knowing if an element is its parent's last child?

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li id="a"></li>
  <li id="b"></li>
  <li id="c"></li>
</ul>

$('#b').isLastChild(); //should return FALSE
$('#c').isLastChild(); //should return TRUE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how do I check if an element is the last sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681581/jquery-how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-the-last-sibling)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector together with .is()

```
$('#c').is(':last-child')
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) like this:

```
$('#b').is(":last-child"); //false
$('#c').is(":last-child"); //true
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MyL7P/).  Another alternative is to check `.next().length`, if it's `0` it's the last element.

Answer (score 11):

```
if($('#b').is(":last-child")){

}
```