# .is() doesn't exist in Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, cheerio

I need to check if an element is last child like this

[Determining if the element is the last child of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209605/determining-if-the-element-is-the-last-child-of-its-parent)

But I use cheerio instead of jquery (for lighter weight) on node.js

https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio

It gave me error:

```
TypeError: Object XXXXXXX has no method 'is'
```

Can someone confirm? If so, what is the elegant way to check if a node is last child?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which adds an `isLastSibling` method for checking if an element is the last sibling.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<p><a>1</a><b>2</b><i>3</i></p>'),
    $fn = Object.getPrototypeOf($());

$fn.isLastSibling = function() {
    return this.parent().children().last()[0] === this[0];
};

console.log(
    $('a').isLastSibling(),
    $('b').isLastSibling(),
    $('i').isLastSibling()
);
```

The output you should get is `false false true` because the `<a>` and `<b>` elements are not the last siblings but the `<i>` element is.

Comment: Actually, `length` 0 when there is next() and `length` ` when it's last child. I just tested. Strange. Can you confirm?

Comment: You're right, it didn't work. I have modified my answer with a complete, tested example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('dom').each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ( $this === $this.parent().last())
            {
                alert('got me!');
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: last() doesn't work in cheerio for some reason. It gave me the whole parent() node instead of the really last one :(

Comment: .last() Will select the last element of a cheerio object

Answer (score 0):

Check the `jquery version` it is using?

You can use `last-child-selector` for this

For example:
`$("div span:last-child").css('background','red');`

Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: I got the latest here and it doesn't use jQuery (I believe): https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio. `div span:last-child` doesn't work because there are many other `non-span` elements in the `parent` that could be last child.