# Detect is child container at the bottom of the parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="cont">
<!-- some elements -->
    <div class="child fixed">Child</div>
</div>
```

`child` is with position `fixed` (class `fixed`). Inside `cont` there are another elements, which make it with higher height than `child`.

I have scroll event on document:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) { ... }
```

I want when some1 scroll and child is at the bottom of `cont` to remove `fixed` class.

How can I detect on scroll (`document` scroll) that some element is at the bottom of some parent element (I mean when bottom of the `child` is in the same position as its parent `cont`.) ?

### Edit

@devlincarnate this is not "how to check is it last child" question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: how do I check if an element is the last sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681581/jquery-how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-the-last-sibling)

Comment: Hi, this is last child. How  question for getting last child and get the position of an element are the same ?

Comment: @devlincarnate you can learn here, what is last child: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: When you remove the `fixed class` what should happen  ? I mean if scrolling back re-assigns the `class`. Any clarifications would really help.

Comment: What do mean by some element is at the bottom of some parent element?

Comment: I mean when bottom of the `child` is in the same scroll position as its parent `cont`.

Comment: I already see, you remove a fixed class and than you're left wondering in perplexity why the entire page jump-snapped and increased in height. That's at least what I got from the question and the code you provided. Create a [mcve] and explain what you're after exactly. Because by simply making an element unfixed is like asking for more problems. Seems you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Thanks,  I want only to detect the bottom positions of these two elements `cont` and `child` relative to the window or document. I don't want more. What I will do after that will complicate the question. The problem here is only detecting bottom positions of these two elements.

Comment: This is my issue. Removing/adding the class don't break the template.

Comment: Or maybe this is your solution https://jsfiddle.net/82hrto9b/ ? - That's what I meant by saying [*"XY-problem"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just don't need JS. This is what I'd do, using CSS `position: sticky` - if I got your question (and problem) right...

```css
* { margin: 0;box-sizing: border-box; }
body { border: 10px dashed #000; }

#footer { background: #0fb; height: 150vh;}
#cont   { background: #0bf; height: 200vh;}
#child  { background: #f0b; height: 20vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="child">CHILD FIXED.... and magical</div>
   CONTENT...
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. It is really elegant and I will use it (not so good support, doesn't matter in this case).