# How can i show hidden input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a question.

When I have form with lets say about 100 hidden input fields, how can I show them one by one after I press enter in the last shown input field?

Comment: Hi there, could you perhaps point to a Codepen or other live sample?

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one?" Do you want a delay between each? How long a delay? What do you mean by "show?" Do you mean change them from `type="hidden"` to `type="text"`, or something else? It would help if you were to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72426362/edit) to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the HTML you are talking about.

Comment: When you press enter in the last input field I want to change the type of the next field from hidden to text

Comment: How can there be a next field if you are already in the last field?

Comment: I will need maybe not more than 20 input fields but I will add 50 or 100 hidden input fields, so I can't reach the last field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds a key handler to each `type="text"` field. The key handler tests whether the field is the last `type="text"` field, and if the key was the Enter key. If so, it finds the next `type="hidden"` field, sets its type to "text", and adds the handler to it.

```js
function callback(e){
    if (
        // If it's the last text field
        $(this).index() == $('#demo input[type="text"]').length - 1
            &&
        // And the key pressed is Enter:
        e.which == 13
    ) {
        // Find next hidden field, change it to text, and add the key handler:
        $(this).next('input[type="hidden"]').prop("type", "text").keypress(callback)
    }
}

// Add key handler to all text fields:
$('#demo input[type="text"]').keypress(callback)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="hidden" value="hidden1">
    <input type="hidden" value="hidden2">
    <input type="hidden" value="hidden3">
</div>
```

References:

[jQuery: how do I check if an element is the last sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681628/378779)

[How can I detect pressing Enter on the keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-can-i-detect-pressing-enter-on-the-keyboard-using-jquery)